# О паронимах реалистический – реалистичный

Tags: грамотная-речь, паронимы

> Здесь довольно занятный street-art. И на лестнице палаццо, на месте
>   утраченного Солимена, уличные художники изобразили свою фреску в нише.
>   **В весьма реалистичной манере**: обнажённый человек, стоя к нам
>   спиной, с грустью смотрит на Везувий, где в сумраке лесов горит один
>   далёкий огонёк. Маняще проплывают облака, но человек прикован…

Гуглятся оба варианта выделенного фрагмента, но верен же только один из? О_о

---

> **реалистический**
>
> Значение: следующий реализму, основанный на принципах реализма.
>
> Примеры: реалистическая живопись, реалистический роман.
>
> **реалистичный**
>
> Значение: соответствующий действительности, вполне практический.
>
> Примеры: реалистичная цель, мысль; реалистичная самооценка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гуглятся не просто случайные варианты употребления "реалистичной/реалистической манеры" письма или изображения, оба варианта гуглятся *во множестве книг*. Видимо, *оба* они верны, но в разных аспектах.

**Реалистичная манера** - непосредственная оценка пишущим автором соответствия изображаемого действительности (правдоподобия, похожести и т. п.).

**Реалистическая манера** - косвенная характеристика, отсылка к традициям реализма, реалистического направления в живописи, с его канонами и условностями. В данном случае автором применена сравнительная степень "**весьма**", поэтому можно предположить, что он имел в виду первый аспект и правильно выбрал прилагательное, не имея в виду "реализм": нельзя назвать манеру отображения "*весьма пост-импрессионистской*" - так и здесь.

Answer (score 2):

Слово "реалистический " согласно словарям имеет два значения.

РЕАЛИСТИЧЕСКИЙ, -ая, -ое. 1. к Реализм (1 зн.). Р-ое искусство. Р-ое направление в музыке. 2. **Книжн. =Реалистичный. Р-ое отношение к действительности. Р. взгляд на вещи. В наш век нужно быть реалистическим человеком**

**А вот у слова "реалистичный" одно значение.**

РЕАЛИСТИЧНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -чен, -чна, -чно. Трезво-практический, основанный на реализме (2 зн.). Р. человек. План реалистичен. Наш век реалистичен. Вполне р-ая личность. <Реалистично, нареч. Р. смотреть на жизнь.

Толковый словарь Кузнецова.

Таким образом правильно:

**1)реалистическая живопись**

**2)реалистическое направление**

**3)реалистическое искусство**

**4)реалистическая деталь   в художественном произведении**

**5)реалистическое произведение**

**6)реалистический смысл**

**7)реалистическая поэзия**

**8)реалистический метод**

**9)реалистический образ**

> *1)Реалистический метод осложнялся элементами романтизма.
> 2)Ее творчество – это явление реалистической прозы.
> 3)Перед нами –  реалистический  портрет.
> 4)“Евгений Онегин” А.С.Пушкина был первым реалистическим романом, “в высшей степени народным произведением”, “энциклопедией русской жизни”.
> 5) А.С.Грибоедов первым в русской литературе сумел создать реалистический образ положительного героя, воплотившего в своем мировоззрении реальные черты человека XIX века.*

**1)реалистичный план
2)реалистичное развитие
3)реалистичная цель
4)реалистичная самооценка
5)реалистичные  явления общественной жизни**

> 1)Задачи, которые я поставил, являются реалистичными.
>
> 2)Это был мудрый и реалистичный совет.
>
> 3)Как помочь детям в постановке реалистичных жизненных целей в самоопределении?